# What is the point of `static char THIS_FILE[] = __FILE__;`?

Tags: visual-c++, memory-leaks, mfc, visual-studio-debugging, memory-leak-detector

### What is the point  of `static char THIS_FILE[] = __FILE__;`?

#### Intro: What does it do? Where does it come from?

MFC, Microsofts native class library for Windows, has a `DEBUG_NEW` macro that tracks memory allocations and the place they happened (in the user code).

For this to work, the VS wizard puts the following code block into every cpp file: (*not* in header files)

```
#ifdef _DEBUG
    #define new DEBUG_NEW
    #undef THIS_FILE
    static char THIS_FILE[] = __FILE__;
#endif
```

and the debug new macro is defined as (in `afx.h`):

```
#define DEBUG_NEW new(THIS_FILE, __LINE__)
```

The whole machinery will result in meaningful leak detection output like:

```
Detected memory leaks!
Dumping objects ->
f:\dd\vctools\vc7libs\ship\atlmfc\src\mfc\strcore.cpp(141) : {615} normal block at 0x04081CE0, 56 bytes long.
 Data: <¬9Í]            > AC 39 CD 5D 13 00 00 00 13 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 
c:\my\dev\path\myfile.cpp(237) : {614} normal block at 0x04087FC0, 4 bytes long.
 Data: <ð   > F0 1C 08 04 
Object dump complete.
```

### So, what's the question again?

What leaves me puzzled is what the `THIS_FILE` char array is for. The machinery doesn't make sense. If they'd defined `DEBUG_NEW`just as:

```
#define DEBUG_NEW new(__FILE__, __LINE__)
```

They could just place it in a header and be done with it instead of having that `ifdef` block in every file.

So, what's the point of `THIS_FILE`?

(Incidentally, this is exactly what MS' CRT does with `malloc` and `_malloc_dbg` where the debug macro is defined in the header `crtdbg.h` as:

```
#define   malloc(s)             _malloc_dbg(s, _NORMAL_BLOCK, __FILE__, __LINE__)
```

)

So again, why is it done the complicated way in the MFC `DEBUG_NEW`macro when the simple way would work (better)???

---

Update: Ha! I recently noticed that the VS2005 wizard *does not* put the definition of `THIS_FILE` into a generated cpp file.

Investigating it, it seems that MS decided some time ago, that it is not neccessary anymore, as in `afxtempl.h` the following is defined:

```
#undef THIS_FILE
#define THIS_FILE __FILE__
```

Still, I guess the question keeps being the same, as to why it was ever neccessary. (And I guess the answer with the memory requirement way back then is pretty valid.)

---

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The debug allocator stores a *pointer* to the file name in the heap block.  Just 4 bytes instead of having every allocated block also having to allocate room for the file name.

Note that this can cause loss of debug info when the leaked block was allocated by a DLL and that DLL was unloaded by the time the leak report is generated.

Only the character array `THIS_FILE` is guaranteed to be always the same in the translaton unit. Not `__FILE__`, that's a literal. And two literals are not guaranteed to have the same address, even if they have the same value, meaning that a compiler could create a distinct literal -- and use up memory -- for each use of `__FILE__`.

Comment: Wouldn't the compiler already store the literal it used as the parameter to the `new` function call? Maybe it's to prevent multiple literals from taking too much space.

Comment: It is and that mattered in old versions of VS.  MFC is *ancient*.

Comment: I don't get it. The signature for the debug new operator (`void* AFX_CDECL operator new(size_t nSize, LPCSTR lpszFileName, int nLine);
`) would always be the same, regardless whether I pass it `__FILE__` or `THIS_FILE`. So where is any memory saved?

Comment: Only THIS_FILE is guaranteed to be always the same.  Not `__FILE__`, that's a literal.  And two literals are not guaranteed to have the same address, even if they have the same value.

Answer (score 0):

I believe, and I could be wrong, that this is delineate the blocks of memory inside the compiled exe. This would help if you were to obtain an exception you could follow back the chain of memory addesses to find the offending code, given you knew what address the dll/exe was loaded at.

Answer (score 0):

`__FILE__` is the same throughout the whole file while `__LINE__` changes on every line.  So if you have lots of debugging code in a file, older compilers that did not merge constants well, would have a lot of unnecessary copies of the string "filename.ext".  You may be able to check the difference with something like -fno-merge-constants (sorry, thats the gcc CFLAG for it, not sure for VS).  Most compilers now merge constants by default, making that definition unnecessary.

Comment: Yeah. Pretty much what I and @HansPassant established in the comments to his answer. Or so I think.